# Login authentication programming pattern

Tags: java, php, android, design-patterns, authentication

i would like to have a discussing with you about a login pattern and ask for your input.

Especially my idea is used for a Androird Applicaion
PHP -> Native Android with AsyncHttpClient -> Activity

I dont need help for the authentication or the login procedure itself. Just about the process afterwards, if a user is already authenticated.

Imaging your having one Activity in Andriod with Login fields, thats refers after a right Login to  another ShowData-Activity.
The Cookie of the Weberver (Apache + PHP) is stored in the SharedPreferences.

If the user is coming back to the application but is still logged in, as his PHPSessionID is still valid, how can we bypass the login Activity and redirect directly to the Data-Activity.

Should there be a second cookie that stores something like "logged_in", "true"
and the Android APP then checks

```
Pseudocode:
(If logged_in-cookie == true) { Start data-activity}
```

Or should there be another call to a site on the webserver that returns a true value?

```
Pseudo:
If(webseite_response==true){redirect to data activity}
```

Im not sure about the  Best practise even under a security point of view.

Even if the user session is not active, someone could just send an "true" to the Andorid application, and then the user would be in the Data-Activity (even if no data is showed there)

Looking forward to your answers.

Best regards
Fabian

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest storing two values in the shared preference
1)a boolean for the logged in status
2)the cookie

The during app startup,check if  logged in status is true,if true you can then verify the cookie.If the cookie is valid,proceed,if its not valid,display the login interface.
Seems like a very nice and easy solution.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your easy best practise. So i should set a cookie with setcookie('login_status', $status_bolean, time() + COOKIE_RUNTIME, "/", COOKIE_DOMAIN); (in PHP for example). And how would you verify the cookie? Could you please clarify that more in detail? I mean am i to paranoia, or wouldnt a user be able to just set local a cookie with the value true, and is then in the DataActivity, of course he wouldnt see anything as he hasnt a valid PHPSessionID. But at least he could enter. How to avoid that? Thanks for your support and the fast reply

Comment: @FabianK During log in,the server can return a json array of the logged_in status and the associated cookie/sessionId which are then stored in the shared preference..Then during loading of the application if status is true,then the associated cookie is verified against the webserver.All this during loading of the app.If the cookie is found to be true,the app redirects to DataActivity,else the user is requested to log in.I don't see how a user can set a cookie since he has n o access to shared preferences. And in any case,a cookie is verified against the server.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at Facebook SDK for android and see how they have implemented the authentication mechanism. It should help.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/